# Get favicon with Goutte

Tags: web-scraping, goutte

i'm trying extract favicon with Goutte library but not working and return an error node not exists.

My code:

```
// Import Goutte here...
$client = new Client();
$url = 'https://riojournal.com/articles.php?id=29319';
$crawler = $client->request( 'GET', $url );
$icon = $crawler->filterXpath('//link[@rel="*"]')->attr('href');
```

What wrong?